# How I can add a static block on product description page after fotorama end?

Tags: magento2

I want to add a block and put pictures in it to show on product description page .

Every page will have different pictures. How can I add this block ?  As on other pages I can add using admin but for product description page how I can ?
**EDIT**
image after adding attribute.

[image: these empty fields]

**EDIT2**
drag and drop of attributes  [image: drag and drop]

Detail.phtml

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
    $theme = $this->helper('Infortis\Base\Helper\Data');

    $showTabs = $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs'); //$block->getData('show_tabs');
    //$mode = $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_mode');
    //$threshold = intval($theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_threshold'));
    //$initCollapsed = $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_collapsed');
    //$reviewsInCollateral = $theme->getCfg('product_page/collateral_reviews');

    $containerClasses = '';
    $tabsClasses = '';
    if ($showTabs)
    {
        $containerClasses .= ' collateral-tabs';
        $tabsClasses .= ' ' . $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_style');
        // $tabsStyle = $theme->getCfg('product_page/tabs_style');
        // switch ($tabsStyle)
        // {
        //     case 'style-luma':
        //         $tabsClasses .= ' style-luma';
        //         break;
        //     case 'style1':
        //         $tabsClasses .= ' style1';
        //         break;
        //     case 'style1-small':
        //         $tabsClasses .= ' style1 style1-small';
        //         break;
        // }
    }
    else
    {
        $containerClasses .= ' collateral-stacked';
    }

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed box-collateral<?php echo $containerClasses; ?>">
        <?php echo  $_product->getAddTextArea();?>
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items<?php echo $tabsClasses; ?>" <?php if ($showTabs): ?>data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>


        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>


<div id="review_container">
<button type="button" id="review_id">Write Review</button>
</div>


<script>

require(['jquery'],function($){
jQuery('#review_id').on('click', function() {


if(!jQuery('form#review-form').is(':visible'))

{

        jQuery('form#review-form').show();
    }
else{

jQuery('form#review-form').hide();

}

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can add this by crate text attribute for product. Add content inside your text attribute and pass your value after fotorama.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya brother can you explain little bit I am new on magento so I cant understand . And I want to post pictures there.

Comment: First just create One product attribute from Stores -> Attribute -> Product  with type Text.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya done . I kept type to media images . as there only 2 of text types as fellow  , 1.text field 2.text area 3.

Comment: Keep text area.

Comment: okay done @RakeshJesadiya . Now ?

Comment: set attribute into your attribute set using Stores -> Attribute -> Attribute set and save and check inside your product page this attribute is display or not.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya  in Attribute Sets only default attribute is appearing .  when I click on it  on next 3 coloum appear . 1 of edit attribute name ,2nd groups 3rd  unassigned group . in the third one my attribute is appearing . So I should  click on my attribute and click on save ?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya if yes doing that I can see a field of that name added to product catalog table in product-> catalog . but nothing is appearing on page

Comment: You have to drag and drop your attribute using right side to your default section just keep inside sku or any attribute from left side of section

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya  I have droped in groups coloum under product description. I am doing right ? kindly check picture I posted

Comment: Now you can check your attributes inside product page and add content

Comment: As There is no option to upload image in it @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: How to add image in it  nad pass it to page kindly a quick guideline please??? @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: just set your attribte as wysiwyg enable from your attribute page.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya that appear aswell . Picture is saving aswell. But not appearing on page ? its last issue . taking your so much time I know

Comment: using this $_product->getAddTextArea() get your value.

Comment: $_product->getAddTextArea('my attribute name') ?  and putting that in my  details phtml ?

Comment: yes in details phtml just keep $_product->getAddTextArea() becasue your attribute name is add_text_area so its display value

Comment: I only added that line in code. nothing is appearing. I have to do any echo ? or do changes in xml ? @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: You need to echo before line

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya  I included my detail.phtml . kindly have a look I am adding this line  <?php echo $_product->getAddTextArea()?>  due to this other div not showing and this one itself